# Неудачная сборка native Hadoop library на Solaris: build.xml does not exist

Tags: ant, сборка, apache, solaris, linux

Действуя согласно [Build native libraries on Solaris](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3123), ввел команду

```
root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin# ant -Dcompile.native=true -Dnonspace.os=SunOS -Dmake.cmd=gmake clean tar
```

и получил в результате

> `Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!  
> Build failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было вводить эту команду на уровень выше, где есть файл `build.xml`